# Javascript get the heighest td>div in each tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic table. Each tr contains 5 td with `product` class. I'm working some kind of script which get's the highest `.product>.content-text` on each row and set the `min and max height` of the `.content-text` to this value, then check the next row, till I have rows.

Now I have this script which gets the maximum of all of the `.product>.content-text` and set it to `.content-text`. But sometimes a smalled `td` would be enough so I would like to check it row after row.

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".content-text").map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());

$(".content-text").css("max-height", maxHeight);
$(".content-text").css("min-height", maxHeight);
```

How can I modify this script to check only for each row, set the last 5 `.content-text` and then skip to the next row.

My html:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
<td class="product"><div class="content-text"></div></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your html also

Comment: @photo_tom Just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class in tr and use :last to choose them.

Or you can use :gt(N) to get the elements index over than N

Comment: XD.. I forget it